# Forward Node log through Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

So I'm using `grunt` so start my node app:

```
grunt.registerTask 'start', ->
  grunt.util.spawn
    cmd: 'coffee'
    args: ['./server/server.coffee']

  grunt.log.write "Started server..."

  grunt.task.run 'watch'
```

But the logs coming from Node are very useful. How can I continue to start my server with Grunt (so it'll do `watch`) but see the Node log instead of or in addition to the Grunt log?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using grunt watch over using a process manager, like supervisor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue recently and solved it like this:

```
grunt.util.spawn
  cmd: 'coffee'
  args: ['./server/server.coffee']
  opts:
    stdio : 'inherit'
```

Comment: Wow! That was easy! Any way to get it on a new line? It echoes `Waiting...Server is running on port 1339.` There should really be a return or two.

Comment: Don't know, sorry. Grunt seems to run those tasks completely detached (and I can't get it to stop that using [`detached: false`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)), so they just dump their output to stdout  completely separate from Grunt.